# python - how do I perform the below task on pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df of timeseries of a hypothetical stock (created randomly) and corresponding returns

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(200,800,100),index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01',periods=100,freq='D'),columns=['stock'])
df['rtns'] = df.stock.pct_change()
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

What I need is, for a given date say 2/1/2015 if we look forward 22 days (3/1/2015 : 24/1/2015), from that distribution I need percentiles (5th, 10th, 25th....as shown in the snap below). Just to  clarify the percentiles to be calculated on returns (not on stock prices). Like wise I want the same for all the dates. How do we do that?

Edited -

I have attached an output for a couple of days. I am not sure what is the python equivalent for np.percentile([array],0.05) i.e. for 5th percentile. I have used exccel function percentile([array],0.05) to populate the output.

[image]

Comment: Can you include input and output in a reproducible format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution could be:

```
df[::-1]["rtns"].shift(1).rolling(22).quantile(0.25)[::-1]
```

`::-1` is for reversing the list so that it can calculate quantiles of date after the given date.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
for pct in [0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95]:
    df[f"{int(pct*100)}th percentile"] = df['rtns'].rolling(22).quantile(pct).shift(-22)

>>> df.head()
            stock      rtns  ...  75th percentile  95th percentile
2015-01-02    435  0.835443  ...         0.251163         0.685605
2015-01-03    272 -0.374713  ...         0.263344         0.736752
2015-01-04    344  0.264706  ...         0.251163         0.736752
2015-01-05    329 -0.043605  ...         0.270500         1.347892
2015-01-06    783  1.379939  ...         0.270500         0.736752
```